# Increase Spacing in an algorithm

Tags: spacing, algorithms

Please, how can i increase spacing in an algorithm, between instruction 1 et instruction 2 ?

```
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{algorithm}[H]
 \caption{My algo}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]
 \STATE instruction 1
 \STATE instruction 2
 \end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm}
 \end{document}
```

i'd like also to increase spacing between line and first instruction (see figure)
[image]

please just another question: is it possible to add the option [vlined] with

```
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algorithmic} ?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

set `\setstretch{1.4}` to any value you like

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \usepackage{setspace}
\let\Algorithm\algorithm
\renewcommand\algorithm[1][]{\Algorithm[#1]\setstretch{1.4}}

\begin{document}
 \begin{algorithm}[H]
 \caption{My algo}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]
 \STATE instruction 1
 \STATE instruction 2
 \end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i edit my question

Comment: use `\caption{\strut My algo}`

Comment: thank you for answer but i'd like have a spaing between the second line and the first instruction 1:

Comment: `\STATE \strut instruction 1` The command `\strut`is the height of the character "(" but without a width. It can be used to get some more space, if needed

Comment: thank you so much , my question about vlined i post it in a new question ?