# How to modify line spacing in algorithm / algpseudocode?

Tags: algorithms, line-spacing

I want to increase line spacing between statements in `algorithm` environment. I used the `setspace` package as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74849/increase-spacing-in-an-algorithm), but it also affects the space between line breaks that is not wanted. The following is a sample code

```
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State lines are long so I get line breaks. I want to increase space between statements, but not between different lines of the same statement.     
\State lines are long so I get line breaks. I want to increase space between statements,  but not between different lines of the same statement.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

In preamble I have:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\algrenewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{{\sf\footnotesize#1}}
\usepackage{setspace}
\let\Algorithm\algorithm
\renewcommand\algorithm[1][]{\Algorithm[#1]\setstretch{1.2}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one possibility; internally, `algorithmic` uses a `\list`, so we can use the `xpatch` package to patch this list adding a desired value for `\itemsep` (in the example I used `2ex plus2pt`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report} 
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\algrenewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{{\sffamily\footnotesize#1}}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\algorithmic}{\itemsep\z@}{\itemsep=2ex plus2pt}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State lines are long so I get line breaks. I want to increase space between statements, but not between different lines of the same statement.     
\State lines are long so I get line breaks. I want to increase space between statements,  but not between different lines of the same statement.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The patching can also be done with the help of `etoolbox` instead of `xpatch`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\algorithmic\endcsname{\itemsep\z@}{\itemsep=2ex plus2pt}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Wouldn't `\xpatchcmd{\algorithmic}{\itemsep\z@}{\itemsep=2ex plus2pt }{}{}` be easier? `:-)`

Comment: @egreg hehe! Of course; I did the change. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I have `etoolbox` but not `xpatch`. I will install `xpatch` and test.

Comment: @Aydin You can use `etoolbox`, but you have to say `\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\algorithmic\endcsname` instead of `\xpatchcmd{\algorithmic}`

Comment: @egreg I've added the `etoolbox` option to my answer; thanks, once again :-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Is there any reason for not just adding \itemsep1mm (or something what fits) directly after \begin{algorithmic} ?